# how do you capture the line before the match regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I need to capture the line before the matching of the regex.

For example, lets's say, these are the lines in the file:

log

```
[2017-03-28 13:32:01,072][pool-JDBCService-785][INFO ][JDBCService.java:21]
 -     JDBCService==>{procId:d555,sessionId:5678

xx <- readLines("C:/log")
grep("procId", xx, value=TRUE)
```

I need to capture this line, right above the procId:

```
[2017-03-28 13:32:01,072][pool-JDBCService-785][INFO ][JDBCService.java:21]
```

how would I do this in R?

Comment: Does that **line** have any pattern ? If yes then define it and try thinking in that direction.

Comment: Assuming you have a vector of these, you could use `myVec[grep("procId:", myVec, fixed=TRUE) - 1]`.

Comment: @Rahul, the log file has many many entries. I need to search for procId and capture the line before it which has the datetime in it.

Comment: As far as I can see, from the info you provided, you have datetime and that **line** within `[ ]` square brackets. Are you looking or something like this ? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3g30T5/1)

Comment: Try `regmatches(s, regexpr(s, ".*(?=\\R.*procId:\\d)", perl=TRUE))`

Comment: Like @lmo said -- just get the line numbers with `grep` and subtract 1.